# How to print newline in a textarea using HTTPRequest?

Tags: php, html, ajax, textarea

I want to print newline in a textarea using HTTPRequest property. 
Here is my code :

```
<script>
function htrt(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    //document.getElementById("txtwrite").innerHTML = str; 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtwrite").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","lecture.php?techtxt=" + str);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<textarea rows="9000" cols="9000" style="height: 200px; width: 725px;" id="txtwrite" readonly="readonly"></textarea>    

<textarea cols="9000" rows="9000" name="txtname" style="height: 200px; width: 725px;" onkeyup="htrt(this.value)"></textarea>
```

Here is lecture.php code :

```
<?php
$str=$_GET['techtxt'];
        echo $str;
?>
```

It does not print newline in textarea. I have used nl2br($string) function to check what happen in the textarea but it does not work.
Please anyone help me.

Comment: I would try json_encode instead of nl2br. You are sending JS data, so it should be JS encoded. And think about using a JS framework, like jQuery, mootools or prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use div instead of textarea. Because no html tags are working in textarea tag but in div it's working.

This function `nl2br()` converts new line to `br` tag. Just learn this function [`nl2br()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shahriar. Your provided link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Before echo it back use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function from PHP, will solve your problem with new lines, from the other textarea.

A jsfiddle test with encoded string: http://jsfiddle.net/gartz/5mEEQ/

This:

```
<a href='te
st'>Test</a>
```

Will became this:

```
&lt;a href=&#039;te&NewLine;st&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt
```

And it between the textarea tags will work like a charm.

But you need change this:

```
document.getElementById("txtwrite").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Into this:

```
document.getElementById("txtwrite").html = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Comment: @NirobHasan did you looked my jsfiddle?!? The example is using textarea and is working. It's because you are using `value`, when you need to use `html` property.

Comment: yes I look jsfiddle. It work in the page where htmlspecials($string) function present but when I use responseText using AJAX it does not work in the root page from where I request a page.

Comment: If I use document.getElementById("txtwrite").html=xmlhttp.responseText; it does not print anything in the textarea.

Comment: what browser you are using to test it? I'm start to think is better you to use json instead plain/text